# For loop won't run in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I have a basic knowledge of coding in C++ but have been following a tutorial and am having trouble following it. I have tried using Debug.Log to find out my problem and it seems my for loop is not running but the function is being called successfully. Can someone help?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class AddButtons : MonoBehaviour {


public Transform puzzleField;
public GameObject btn;

void Awake()
{
    Debug.Log("Awake Function Started");
    for(int i=0; i>8; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("loop started");
        GameObject button = Instantiate(btn);
        button.name = "" + i;
        button.transform.SetParent(puzzleField, false);
    }
}
}
```

The debug log shows "Awake Function Started" correctly as expected but "loop started" doesnt show in the log. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 11):

In your for loop, your condition is `i>8`, which won't be true for the first iteration, so the loop is skipped.  You probably meant `i<8`.

Comment: Thank you so much! 

2 hours of staring at the screen gone to waste. You live and learn :)

Answer (score 4):

Actually for-loop contains of **for(initialization;condition;increment/decrement)**

- Initialization: Any variable should be initialized here on which whole for loop will depends. It runs only once.
- Condition: It is the condition on which for loop executes if gets true, per loop. It runs every time after every loop and executes the loop until it gets false.
- Increment/Decrement: In loop variable. Although you can do anything in it.

In your case you put i=0 and condition i>8 which is not true, that's why your loop is not executing.